# Where to ask about computational code about mismatched results with scientific theories?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked a question on Physics about an unproducible code, and it was close voted as not about physics: [How to plot forcing oscillation with damping correctly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355610/how-to-plot-forcing-ocillation-with-damping-correctly?noredirect=1#comment796011_355610).

Since the nature of the question is about mismatched results with scientific theories not fixing bugs, I think Stack Overflow or Code Review are not a right place. Mathematics can work for common problems, but again not a good fit if it requires knowledge outside math. The last thing I can come up is Computational Science, which seems the right choice for algorithms, but [the topic must be in applied math](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355610/how-to-plot-forcing-ocillation-with-damping-correctly?noredirect=1#comment796011_355610). The question [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598) assumes that I've coded correctly in principle.

Where can I ask such questions?

Comment: The question [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598) assumes that I've coded correctly in principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag line for [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), visible on the [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science) says:

> #### Computational Science
>
> Q&A for scientists using computers to solve scientific problems

That sounds exactly like what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of Physics explicitly says:

> **Implementation details of computational tasks**
>   While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic. It may be suitable for Computational Science or Stack Overflow, however.